# Can't seem to access my server either through public IP or ssh into the server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache, aws-security-group, user-data

I have provisioned an EC2 instance in default VPC which has both private and public IP address. Deployed through terraform and configuration includes a user-data script for  an Apache webserver and security groups are opened ports 22, 80, 443 from anywhere. I can neither seem to connect the webserver through my Public IP nor through ssh into the box. My user-data script is below

```
#! /bin/bash
# Instance Identity Metadata Reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-identity-documents.html
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y httpd
sudo systemctl enable httpd
sudo service httpd start
sudo systemctl restart sshd && systemctl status sshd  
sudo echo '<h1>Welcome to StackSimplify - APP-1</h1>' | sudo tee /var/www/html/index.html
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/app1
sudo echo '<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body style="background-color:rgb(250, 210, 210);"> <h1>Welcome - APP-1</h1> <p>Terraform Demo</p> <p>Application Version: V1</p> </body></html>' | sudo tee /var/www/html/app1/index.html
sudo curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document -o /var/www/html/app1/metadata.html
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: user-data is not a problem. Can you describe terraform code if possible?

Comment: Are you sure that the instance was launched in a Public Subnet? Was a keypair specified during the launch? (You can see that in the EC2 management console).  What happens when you try to SSH into the instance -- does it fail immediately (indicating bad keypair), or does it take a few seconds before it fails (indicating no network connection)?